# What's a trendy word for an 'information capsule'. A short snippet of information

Tags: expressions, idiom-requests

In French we might say 'info-capsule' to designate a short block of information. There may be 'info-capsules' on a variety of topics but they are always short and may point to other resources.

What would be a trendy name to designate these information snippets(?) ?

Comment: Depending on the context the word you may be looking for is soundbite. We use this in politics to describe sayings by politicians that last a period of less than 30 seconds or so.

Answer (score 1):

**Snippet**, which you referenced, is already one word for a small piece of information.

A **blurb** would be one word you might use particularly in reference to self-advertisement of a book, movie, or product.

A **tidbit** has connotations of gossip or news, or used to describe something that is secret, overheard, or Incidentally acquired.

A **nugget** (via RegDwigнt)  can describe a small lump of anything, including information, often in the form of a proverb or "nugget of wisdom."

You said "trendy" but more formally an **abstract** is a summary of a text or a scientific article.

A **synopsis** is a summary of a book or movie plot, or more generally, a condensed summary of a particular topic.

Comment: *Nugget* is another one.

Answer (score 1):

In publishing, **sidebar** is a term for information placed adjacent to an article in a printed or Web publication, graphically separate but with contextual connection

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidebar_(publishing)